# docker push to private registry hangs

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have setup, both the repl supplied docker-registry and the official docker registry image from docker hub both have the same issue I am seeing.

I have an image which I have tagged with the docker registry hostname and port etc, and try and push it to the registry.

On hitting enter, it appears to run ok, checking for image layers the registry already has. Once it starts to push an image layer it doesn't have, it hangs; and stays there, forever until I ctrl+c out of it

Example:

```
[root@docker1 ~]# docker push docker1:5000/centos:7
The push refers to a repository [docker1:5000/centos] (len: 1)
Sending image list
Pushing repository docker1:5000/centos (1 tags)
Image 511136ea3c5a already pushed, skipping
Image 5b12ef8fd570 already pushed, skipping
5c5681003a50: Pushing [>                                                  ] 1.584 MB/220.5 MB 2m9s
```

In the docker logs for the docker-registry container thats running, it has:

```
10.10.10.2 - - [06/Apr/2015:17:11:01 +0000] "PUT /v1/images/f6808a3e4d9e80a655ec625e38b869ed8a614611e4d0073aeff23be841c9fcff/json HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "docker/1.1.1 go/go1.2.1 git-commit/bd609d2 kernel/3.15.3-tinycore64 os/linux arch/amd64"
06/Apr/2015:17:11:02 +0000 DEBUG: args = {'image_id': u'f6808a3e4d9e80a655ec625e38b869ed8a614611e4d0073aeff23be841c9fcff'}
```

and no errors as far as I can see.

I have tried pushing from a remote server on and locally to itself, and still the same. iptables is off, as is selinux.

Not really sure what else to try.

Regards,
K

Comment: Are you using S3? or another distributed filesystem? is your registry running inside boot2docker? what version of the registry is that? what version of docker?

Comment: @MangledDeutz Not S3 or boot2docker no. Just a CentOS host running docker, with the official registry image running in the container.

The registry is the latest from the hub, after doing a docker pull registry - this afternoon.

`[root@docker1 ~]# docker version
Client version: 1.4.1
Client API version: 1.16
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 5bc2ff8/1.4.1
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.4.1
Server API version: 1.16
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Git commit (server): 5bc2ff8/1.4.1`

Comment: I experience the same issue being on a unreliably WiFi network. Can you test it from another host or another network to isolate the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately @VincentH. even docker talking to the registry it, itself is running on the same machine, has the same problem. i.e docker push localhost:5000/blah:1

Answer (score 0):

I did find out in my tests, that if I pushed to localhost it would work fine, but going via the main interface it would fail. Again no IPTables etc running.

I have got around the problem, by pulling the nginx image, and running that a proxy_pass on that to the registry.

I did have to set

`client_max_body_size 0;`

as was getting 411 Length Required' errors, initially.

This is a happy workaround, as I would eventually like to put htaccess in front of it anyway, so C'est la vie.

K